# Mysql select all rows meeting given criteria and other rows with same ID as the selected rows

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Say I have this table:

[image]

The table has lots of rows in it, with DimCombinationID identifying rows that belong to the same group of rows.

I want to do a select with a where like: where (Dimension = 1 AND DimensionValue = 13) AND (Dimension = 5 AND DimensionValue = 15) which should retrieve all rows that have a DimCombinationID of 22 and 56 because they meet both requirements:

[image]

I tried all sorts of things but this explains most what I wrongly get:

Select DimCombinationID from TESTDimCombinations where (DimID = 1 AND DimValueID = 13) OR (DimID = 5 AND DimValueID = 15)

This will get DimCombinationIDs 22, 39 and 56. So all. While only 22 and 56 meet both criteria and 39 should not be in the response of the db.

Once I only have the desired 22 and 56, I want to wrap this query into an outer query which gets all columns for all rows which have DimCombinationID 22 or 56.

I think I need to do something with having or having count but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help or thoughts about how to do this would be greatly appreciated.....I can't wrap my head around this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY for each table?

Comment: I have an ID column, auto incremented. But I use the DimCombinationID because there can be a lot of rows that belong to the same dimension combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
select *
from TESTDimCombinations
where DimCombinationID in (
  select DimCombinationID 
  from TESTDimCombinations
  where (DimID = 1 AND DimValueID = 13) OR (DimID = 5 AND DimValueID = 15)
  group by DimCombinationID 
  having count(*) = 2
);
```

The subquery:

```
select DimCombinationID 
from TESTDimCombinations
where (DimID = 1 AND DimValueID = 13) OR (DimID = 5 AND DimValueID = 15)
group by DimCombinationID 
having count(*) = 2
```

gets the `DimCombinationID`s 22 and 56.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFdbinoJT6QiPtbuBbwKEj/1).
Results:

```
| DimCombinationID | DimID | DimValueID |
| ---------------- | ----- | ---------- |
| 22               | 1     | 13         |
| 22               | 2     | 9          |
| 22               | 5     | 15         |
| 22               | 2     | 2          |
| 56               | 1     | 13         |
| 56               | 2     | 17         |
| 56               | 5     | 15         |
| 56               | 2     | 51         |
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it! I just knew it could be done but somehow I couldn't get my thoughts straight. Very helpful, thanks very much.

Comment: It seems like there's further scope for optimization.

Comment: @Dave33 you already accepted my answer but on a second read I think it did not produce  the correct results. Try my new answer.

Comment: @forpas my question was part of a bigger 'plan'. The answer you gave me helped me squash a part of it that I was stuck with so I was/am happy with it. For instance, I had put the group by having count in your query and changed it a bit further to make it work for what I wanted it for. I needed help with how to get it working and you helpend me a lot so that's why I excepted it. But you're right, if your answer wasn't quite 100% for the question I asked I maybe shouldn't have accepted it then. But now you edited your answer, it's acceptable again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I see no functional difference between the accepted answer and the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
  FROM TESTDimCombinations x
  JOIN TESTDimCombinations y
    ON y.DimCombinationID = x.DimCombinationID 
 WHERE (DimID = 1 AND DimValueID = 13) 
    OR (DimID = 5 AND DimValueID = 15)
```

Comment: Interesting yes! is this because the common perception is that joining is faster or any other reason? I tried it out but for now (small data set) there doesn't seem to be a speed difference, but I'm wondering what you think and say.

Comment: The only way of understanding query performance is by providing the EXPLAIN for each given query, together with SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables.